# Laravel application on ubuntu 20.4 throws composer error

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-20.04, laravel-9

I am completely knew to server management, and have a ubuntu 20.4 instance to launch a PHP-Laravel 9 application.

So far, I have install PHP 8, mysql, nginx, composer, downloaded a laravel application with composer and moved to /var/www/html, meaning that the path to my app is:

```
/var/www/html/my-app
```

My .env looks like the following:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

What would it be or where can I find the correct APP_URL?

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I localhost the correct database host?

I then ran the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

When configured the file to look like this:

```
server {

      listen 80;
      server_name ip-111-222-11-111;
      root /var/www/html/my-app/public;
      add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
      add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
      index index.php;
      charset utf-8;
      location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
      }

       location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
       location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
       error_page 404 /index.php;
       location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
       location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
          deny all;
       }
  }
```

To ssh, I use:

```
ssh ubuntu@12.12.12.12
```

So I assumed that the 12.x.x.x address is the one I should use to access the site through the browser, but when I hit that address in the browser, I see the following:

```
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0".
```

If I check the PHP version, I get the following:

```
PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: May 17 2022 16:48:09) (NTS)
```

How do I access the site through the browser?

Why do I have to run composer install using sudo?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this error? I've came across the same error too. I had PHP 8.1.7 running but Composer said `Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0".`

Comment: No solution found yet.

Comment: I've found mine, my client was using Apache2 which it will use its PHP package instead of the one I've installed on the server.
You can try some of these possible solutions;
1) Don't iInstall Composer packages as administrator
2) Nginx and your server might serving different PHP versions. Maybe you can check on this line; `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;`. Using `which php` command will show the PHP directory the server is running. Your server and webserver can run different PHP versions.

Good luck!